# custom script in Azure ARM template not executed

Tags: azure, deployment, cloud, azure-rm-template

Consider the following ARM template:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgazzin/az104/master/vm.json

It is all executed properly unless the last step:

```
    {
  "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "[concat(concat(variables('vmWeb0xName'), copyIndex()),'/CustomScript')]",
  "location": "[variables('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(variables('vmWeb0xName'), copyIndex()))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
    "type": "CustomScript",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
      "commandToExecute": "[parameters('commandToExecute')]",
      "fileUris": "[split(parameters('fileUris'), ' ')]"
    }
  },
  "copy": {
    "name": "vmCopy",
    "count": "[parameters('vmWebCount')]"
  }
}
```

fileUris has the following value:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgazzin/az104/master/install_vms.sh

Most of the times it is stuck in the "Created" status:

[image]

Does anyone know why it is not getting completed? Any workaround?

Comment: add logging to the script and you can figure that out. also, this extension should have logs under /var/log or something

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are logs in /var/log/azure. One is the following:

```
    + /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript-2.1.3/bin/custom-script-extension install
time=2020-11-12T08:58:29Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=install seq=0 event=start
time=2020-11-12T08:58:29Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=install seq=0 status="not reported for operation (by design)"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:29Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=install seq=0 event="migrate to mrseq" error="Can't find out seqnum from /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript-2.1.3/status, not enough files."
time=2020-11-12T08:58:29Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=install seq=0 event="created data dir" path=/var/lib/waagent/custom-script
time=2020-11-12T08:58:29Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=install seq=0 event=installed
time=2020-11-12T08:58:29Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=install seq=0 status="not reported for operation (by design)"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:29Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=install seq=0 event=end
Writing a placeholder status file indicating progress before forking: /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript-2.1.3/status/0.status
+ nohup /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript-2.1.3/bin/custom-script-extension enable
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event=start
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event=pre-check
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="comparing seqnum" path=mrseq
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="seqnum saved" path=mrseq
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="reading configuration"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="read configuration"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="validating json schema"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="json schema valid"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="parsing configuration json"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="parsed configuration json"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="validating configuration logically"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="validated configuration"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="creating output directory" path=/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="created output directory"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 files=1
time=2020-11-12T08:58:31Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 file=0 event="download start"
time=2020-11-12T08:58:36Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 file=0 event="download complete" output=/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0
time=2020-11-12T08:58:36Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="executing command" output=/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0
time=2020-11-12T08:58:36Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="executing protected commandToExecute" output=/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0
Not writing a placeholder status file, already exists: /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript-2.1.3/status/0.status
+ nohup /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript-2.1.3/bin/custom-script-extension enable
time=2020-11-12T09:04:51Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event=start
time=2020-11-12T09:04:51Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event=pre-check
time=2020-11-12T09:04:51Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event="comparing seqnum" path=mrseq
time=2020-11-12T09:04:51Z version=v2.1.3/git@4cd2b9f-clean operation=enable seq=0 event=exit message="the script configuration has already been processed, will not run again"
```

If I go to directory /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0 there are stderr and stdout. At the end of stdout there is:

```
  Installing : libcap-2.22-11.el7.i686                                  428/809 
  Installing : systemd-libs-219-73.el7_8.9.i686                         429/809 
  Installing : rdma-core-22.4-4.el7_8.i686                              430/809 
  Cleanup    : WALinuxAgent-2.2.11-1.el7.centos.noarch                  431/809 
warning: %postun(WALinuxAgent-2.2.11-1.el7.centos.noarch) scriptlet failed, signal 15
```

So, it really seems the scripts gets executed but it fails.
Thanks.